# Is the Mass flow rate (Mass flux) a scalar quantity?

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate) states that mass flow rate is a scalar quantity, however

Mass Flow Rate= Density x Cross Sectional Area x Velocity

and velocity is a vector quantity, so this would imply Mass Flow Rate is a vector?

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually
$$\mathrm{Mass \space flow \space rate} = \mathrm{Density}(\vec{\mathrm{Area}}\cdot \vec{\mathrm{velocity}})$$

Here $\vec{\mathrm{Area}}$ is the vector perpendicular to the Cross-sectional area and having magnitude equal to the cross-sectional area.

So the dot-product yields a scalar quantity.